# Turn Newrelic monitoring on or off via rest api

Tags: asp.net, newrelic

I am trying to exclude certain times where I don't want new relic to track my application. There is an automated agent that runs in the night, and during that time period I would like to turn the monitoring off and then turn it back on after the agent is done.

Comment: What platform are you using? Ruby, Heroku, ASP.NET?

Comment: Currently new relic is monitoring asp.net platform.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available at this time. Please submit a feature request at [support.newrelic.com](https://support.newrelic.com/anonymous_requests/new).