# With new relic's http api, how do you turn off uptime monitoring?

Tags: curl, heroku, newrelic

I am attempting to turn off uptime monitoring, using curl, per the instructions given in new relics documentation here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/availability-monitor-settings

According to this documentation, this request will disable my uptime monitoring:

curl https://www.myhost.com/accounts/acct_id/applications/app_id/ping_targets/disable -X POST -H "X-Api-Key: "my_key"

Here is the request that I am using (stripped of personal info): curl "https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/NNNNNN/applications/NNNNNNN/ping_targets/disable" -X POST -H "X-Api-Key:x...x"

I have used my acct_id, app_id, and x-api-key successfully for other GET commands. However when I attempt the above command I get this error:

```
<hash>
  <error>The requested page could not be found</error>
</hash>
```

According to this stack exchange post: [Turn Newrelic monitoring on or off via rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417880/turn-newrelic-monitoring-on-or-off-via-rest-api) there is not a way to do this, but that conflicts with the documentation.

So, is there a way to accomplish this? Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "uptime monitoring" refers to Availability Monitoring, this must be accomplished by disabling the policy that controls the monitoring. This can be found by using a command like this to determine the policy id number

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alert_policies.xml' -gH "X-Api-Key:<APIKEY>" -i -d 'filter[name]=<POLICY_NAME>'
```

If the policy name contains spaces, substitute with '+'.

From the output, locate the POLICY_ID

```
<alert_policies_response>
  <alert_policies>
    <alert_policy>
      <id>104446</id>    <----<<<< POLICY_ID
      <type>application</type>
      <name><POLICY_NAME></name>
      .....
```

Also identify the condition id by scanning the output for 'availability' and note the ID number.

```
   <condition>
     <id>997294</id>   <----<<<<   CONDITION_ID
     <type>application_availability</type>
     <severity>downtime</severity>
     ....
```

Now use the resultant POLICY_ID and CONDITON_ID to disable the policy.

```
curl -X PUT 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alert_policies/<POLICY_ID>.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:<APIKEY>' -i \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d \
'{
  "alert_policy": 
    {
    "conditions": [
       {
         "id": <CONDITION_ID>,
         "enabled": false
       }]
    }
 }'
```

Note that once the POLICY_ID and CONDITION_ID are determined, only the last command is required.

Comment: you are completely right. The documentation was for version 1 of the api and my instance uses version 2.  Upon additional research I discovered better documentation here: https://rpm.newrelic.com/api/explore and you have to select your application in the top right corner to see the Alert Policies options here: https://rpm.newrelic.com/api/explore/alert_policies/update

Comment: Thank you Very Much for the answer, it helped me to get started with V2.